# WIFI option stopped showing on an external ssd

Tags: wifi, external-hdd, pop-os

[SOLVED]

I have a Lenovo Yoga 730C and Pop Os as the operating system on it. It works perfectly fine, however, I also have another Pop Os installed on an external SSD and when I try to boot from it, the wifi option doesn't show up. All I could find on the internet says that my network card might not be supported but my Pop Os installation from computer SSD works just great but not on external SSD. It used to be working just fine but it all changed the moment I activated legacy boot to test one of my other external SSDs. After I turned off legacy boot the problem of not having the wifi option still remains.

[EDIT]

So I ran this.

```
lspci
```

Output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dea (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
6b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev ff)
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/SN750 / PC SN720 NVMe SSD
```

Here I found my network controller to be identified as '6b:00.0'

So I ran

```
dmesg | grep '6b:00'
```

And here is the output

```
[    0.517983] pci 0000:6b:00.0: [8086:2526] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.518062] pci 0000:6b:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x71200000-0x71203fff 64bit]
[    0.518435] pci 0000:6b:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.563188] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't claim BAR 0 [mem 0x71200000-0x71203fff 64bit]: no compatible bridge window
[    0.599204] pci 0000:6b:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[    0.599206] pci 0000:6b:00.0: BAR 0: trying firmware assignment [mem 0x71200000-0x71203fff 64bit]
[    0.599209] pci 0000:6b:00.0: BAR 0: [mem 0x71200000-0x71203fff 64bit] conflicts with PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x5d800000-0xdfffffff window]
[    0.599213] pci 0000:6b:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[   10.385890] pci 0000:6b:00.0: [8086:2526] type 00 class 0x028000
[   10.386037] pci 0000:6b:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x71200000-0x71203fff 64bit]
[   10.386456] pci 0000:6b:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[   10.387134] pci 0000:6b:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[   10.387137] pci 0000:6b:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[   10.597765] iwlwifi 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   10.597777] iwlwifi 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   10.597919] iwlwifi 0000:6b:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[   10.612056] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:6b:00.0 failed with error -22
[   25.065908] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   50.673817] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   53.937799] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   53.963138] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   53.978640] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.012035] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.141792] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.170141] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.183485] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.208062] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.220564] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.249336] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.343603] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.375170] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.396452] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.432411] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.445667] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   54.545826] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.373739] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.384065] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.408213] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.419977] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.433090] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.442499] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.461047] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   55.473981] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   56.521829] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.573786] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.593158] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.610989] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.632575] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.646756] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.662430] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.679994] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.696032] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.710371] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.761776] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.778515] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.792264] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.807617] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.819786] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.837330] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.853262] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.864649] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.877788] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.894725] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.908588] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.922697] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.941346] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.957466] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.977677] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  118.996517] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.007331] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.028102] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.125824] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.138729] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.153134] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.169341] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.183303] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.194699] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.207359] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.221197] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.236140] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.287786] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.335996] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.349101] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.368944] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  119.405515] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  120.945831] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  120.985214] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  123.025745] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  123.053858] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  125.101793] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  125.122520] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  127.161761] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  127.184092] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  129.225783] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  129.250935] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  131.293795] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  131.327911] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  133.369898] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  133.406167] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  135.449923] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  135.539671] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6278.225558] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6279.585662] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6279.602306] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6279.616039] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6279.626997] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6282.997588] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6283.040147] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6283.053835] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6283.069221] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.233490] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.247791] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.263630] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.276811] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.290810] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.304816] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.320221] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.421467] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.443190] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.456193] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.471702] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6307.485133] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.337535] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.350179] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.367622] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.380415] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.394800] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.409080] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.426294] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.517542] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.534330] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.550385] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.567575] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.587289] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.612216] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.713564] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.733845] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.753819] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.786729] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.806919] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.909595] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.929504] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.949298] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6322.967625] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.073590] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.102141] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.129517] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.162232] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.261573] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.283063] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.302924] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.321948] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.349891] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.445556] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.466813] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.483387] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.513470] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.529033] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.555487] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.610651] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.632073] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.647916] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.662759] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.678889] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.697995] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6323.797634] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6324.005573] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6324.022720] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.713706] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.726947] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.760803] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.774855] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.788605] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.801796] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.897704] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.911840] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.925729] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.940752] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.971219] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6351.985956] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6352.890074] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6352.924790] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6352.950853] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6352.971347] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6352.996978] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.101686] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.116390] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.130087] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.160900] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.175902] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.191446] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6353.205742] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6500.089999] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.478277] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.517344] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.534121] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.547745] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.577509] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.673931] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.690186] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.702765] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.717353] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.730637] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.746657] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.760260] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.945978] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.966533] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.981580] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6515.994641] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.027580] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.042108] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.137994] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.156236] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.169730] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.182837] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.198171] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 6516.242597] pci 0000:6b:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
```

From now on I have no clue what to do next.

[UPDATE]

As it turned out I updated my kernel on my external ssd and this update made it incompatible with my network card... So nothing mysterious here just me being silly.

Comment: You start by checking if the kernel recognizes your Wifi hardware, e.g. using the `ip`, `lspci` or `dmesg` commands. If not, you probably need to add drivers. Next, find out which network manager is configured and why it does not set up the interface.

Comment: @berndbausch I have updated my outputs under the [EDIT] section of the question.

Comment: I can only suggest to search the internet for the error messages and draw conclusions from the results. Perhaps firmware could not be loaded, etc. Quite a few results for *"iwlwifi: probe" " failed with error -22"*, for example.

Comment: This: https://askubuntu.com/a/1165506 indicates incompatibilities with some kernel version(s).

Comment: Ooooh I c, I recently updated my external SSD version of Pop Os which might be the cause of it. I was very confused by the fact that it works on one version of pop and not on the other. But now I see that it is indeed very possible. I guess I just wait for the next kernel update to fix this issue... I will mark this as solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on finding the solution youself. However, please don't edit your question to contain the answer - write [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead.